# Fragments, ContentProviders and cursors on orientation change

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-orientation, android-cursorloader

Please help me understand what's happening here.

I have two fragments (A and B) in tabs reading data from different tables, via a CursorLoader and aContentProvider, in a Sqlite-database. With different URIs I can change which table the ContentProvider is quering.

I works as expected when switch between the tabs A and B, unless I switch to B, rotate and switches back to A the wrong cursor is returned. The cursor from fragment B is returned instead of a cursor for fragment A with makes the listView in fragment A to cause a crash. In some way the cursor seems to be reused on a rotation.

Why is this happening and how can I prevent that the wrong cursor is returned?

This is what I have in both fragment A and B. Tried to assing a loader id with no success.

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(mLoaderId, null, this);
}
```

My ContentProvider looks like this:

```
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    Cursor cursor = null;       

    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
    case ALL_NEWS:
        queryBuilder.setTables(NewsDb.SQLITE_TABLE);
        cursor = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection,
                selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
        break;

    case SINGLE_PLACE:
        queryBuilder.setTables(PlacesDb.SQLITE_TABLE);
        String id = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
        queryBuilder.appendWhere(PlacesDb.KEY_ID + "=" + id);
        cursor = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection,
                selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
        break;

    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI: " + uri);
    }


    return cursor;

}
```

Comment: 1. Why are you restarting the `Loader` in `onResume()`? When using `CursorLoader` the data is automatically updated. 2. Are you using the `Loader`s in the `Activity`? If so, why?

Comment: 1. Hm. Good question. I basically am following this tutorial: http://sunil-android.blogspot.se/2013/04/android-database-content-provider.html 2. I am not using the loader in the Activity, only initing the loader onCreateView() in each fragment like this: https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html

Comment: Are you still there? I've posted an answer.

Comment: Sorry for my absence. I think I have found what caused my problems. The fragments where initialized twice when rotating due to savedState in the main activity (lots of questions regarding this here) and so forth. But still you have some valid points which helped in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `CursorLoader`, data changes are automatically observed, so you should definitely remove the `restartLoader` call in your `onResume()`. If implemented properly, you should only have to call `initLoader` in `onActivityCreated` of the `Fragment`.

`LoaderManager` IDs are only scoped to the `Fragment`, so you should be using a `static constant` ID. If the `Loaders` *are* handled in the `Fragments`, themselves, it's perfectly fine for every `Fragment` to have the same `Loader` ID (even if they're managed by the same `Activity`).

So in each `Fragment`:

```
private static final int LOADER_ID = 0;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // ...

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
}
```